# Desktop screenshots with Matlab

Tags: matlab, timer, screenshot

Right now I'm using a program called MWSnap to capture and save desktop screenshots. I'd like to find a way to capture repeated screenshots on a timer (e.g. take a screenshot every 5 mins).

Is there a way to do this with matlab? If not, do you have any suggestions on other programs with this functionality? Or is there a way to program this in C++ or C#?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
i = 1;
while true
    robo = java.awt.Robot;
    t = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    %# Set the capture area as the size for the screen
    rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());

    %# Get the capture
    image = robo.createScreenCapture(rectangle);

    %# Save it to file
    filehandle = java.io.File(sprintf('capture%d.jpg', i));
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image,'jpg',filehandle);

    pause(300) %# Wait for 5 min
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Just press `ctrl+break` to end your program. (Note that I've used [this code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11363-screencapture) as the capture part)

Answer (score 0):

You could invoke Java from Matlab (very easy) and do something like [this](http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=16400&tstart=0). You could invoke that and pause for 5 minutes and the execute again in a loop.